# Simpledateformat didn't check date validation?

Tags: java, date-format

I have a REST api which involving date conversions. For that it has inputs like a `dateString` and its `format` .But my problem is I can't validate the date for some negative scenarios. For example

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("29-09-2014 20:35:27");
```

I expect the above code will throw exception, but it doesn't. So my validation fails. 
Can anyone suggest a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the `DateFormat` to parse strictly, instead of leniently (the default):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setLenient(false);
sdf.parse("29-09-2014 20:35:27"); // Throws ParseException
```

Comment: thanks. most useful thing is it also validate the given date also

Comment: there no method like setLenient in java.text.SimpleDateFormatter

Comment: @GunjanShah: There's no such class as `java.text.SimpleDateFormatter`, but `setLenient` is declared in `DateFormat`, which `SimpleDateFormat` is a subclass of.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, It was my misunderstanding. I agree with your answer. The method is defined in DateFormat class. Extremely sorry for wrong comment ..